# Insert the contents of a Word Document into an email and include the default signature using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I used the code provided by Patrick Wynne in [How to send a Word document as body of an email with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609112/how-to-send-a-word-document-as-body-of-an-email-with-vba/35610600#35610600?newreg=e67ff8c3dc434db1a3aa97807c67a847), but it overwrites the signature. Is there a way to change the code to leave the default signature in place when pasting the contents of the word document?

Here is the code:

```
Sub emailFromDoc()
    Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim oMail As MailItem

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wd.documents.Open(...path to your doc...)
    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close
    set wd = Nothing

    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With oMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182385/4539709

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
Sub emailFromDoc()
    Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim Rng As Object
    Dim oMail As MailItem

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set doc = wd.documents.Open(...path to your doc...)
    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close
    Set wd = Nothing

    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With oMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        Set Rng = editor.Content
        Rng.Collapse 1
        Rng.Paste
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! It sure beats the temporary workaround I implemented with SendKeys.